# Python error - OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, overflow

My program gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Simulation\SymDialog.py", line 153, in OnPaint
    self.Redraw(False)
  File "C:\Simulation\SymDialog.py", line 173, in Redraw
    obj.Draw(self.dc)
  File "C:\Simulation\SymDialog.py", line 207, in Draw
    dc.DrawCircle(self._x, self._y, self._r)
  File "E:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_gdi.py", line 3391, in DrawCircle
    return _gdi_.DC_DrawCircle(*args, **kwargs)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Method from error:

OnPaint

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    self.Redraw(False)
    wx.GCDC(wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self._buffer))
    event.Skip()
```

Redraw

```
def Redraw(self, clear):
    if clear == True: del self.drawList[:]
    self.dc = wx.GCDC(wx.BufferedDC(None, self._buffer))
    self.dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
    self.dc.Clear()
    for obj in self.drawList:
        obj.Draw(self.dc)
    del self.dc
```

Draw

```
def Draw(self, dc):
    self.setDC(dc)
    dc.DrawCircle(self._x, self._y, self._r)
```

How can I fix this error ?
Thanks for answers

Comment: Stop trying to use values that are too large.

Comment: DrawCircle takes some parameters, but you're passing it values that are too big. Try to pass it smaller values.

Comment: But the values ​​"self._x, self._y" is not too big, are in the range (0, 600), because this is size of panel where circles are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You might be mistakenly using too large values.

Edit: Since I can't comment, what are the sizes of self._x, self._y, and self._r?

Comment: The C part can't be changed; it's a call into the Windows API.